# How to programatically add a file to a Class Library Project ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to programatically generate a file in one of the class library projects in my solution. Is there a way to do this? By programatically, I mean a method that can create a `.cs` file and add to the project or one of its folders.

Comment: You can generate C# source files, but what do you want exactly? C# is not a dynamic language so those files are just files and won't be part of your running app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.Reflection.Emit` to do this. [Here](http://www.drdobbs.com/generating-code-at-run-time-with-reflect/184416570) is a tutorial.